# Capture all Authorized Transaction at 12AM - Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on Magento and willing to know if its possible that I set the Authorize.net to only "Authorize" from the admin settings and at 12AM daily capture the payments for all "Authorized" & "Invoiced" transactions for the previous day or same day orders.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You would need to create an extension and set up a cron job that runs at 12AM.

In the method, get a collection of desired orders, loop through each order, and capture payment while creating invoices..

There is a plethora of online tutorials for everything I've listed here.